# Help understanding inductor formula in boost converter

Tags: led, boost, driver, converter

I'm designing an LED light array and have chosen the [MC34844](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC34844.pdf) LED driver from NXP. I have elected to go with I2C control mode and a 14S8P array of blue LEDs with the following parameters:

- Input voltage: 12 V
- Output voltage: ~45 V
- Output current: 160 mA (20 mA * 8 parallel)

I have followed the calculations from page 27 of the datasheet and have got reasonable values, but I've made a few assumptions that could be wrong.

1. Duty cycle: calculated to be ~0.738

   - Vd assumed to be about 0.8 V (diode forward voltage)
   - Vsw 0.04 V (Rdson = 0.25 Ω and output current 160 mA)
2. Inductor (equation 3):

   - Rw assumed to be 0.2 Ω (estimating as I can't choose an inductor without an inductance value)
   - r - input current ratio. I don't quite understand whether it's ripple current or input/output current ratio and it's not explained in the data sheet.

[image: Inductor equation]

3. Right Half Plane Zero Frequency:

   - Calculating with the given equation I get about 19.2 kHz but it says to push it to higher frequencies. Does this mean you can arbitrarily choose a higher frequency than this?

[image]

Comment: What switching frequency? What's the lowest value of the input voltage. Ditto the highest value.

Comment: Switching frequency is 300khz. I wouldn't imagine more than 100mV input ripple but hopefully less. Does the input current ratio make sense?

Comment: I think you mean series LEDs don't you @aggo or, you mean an output voltage that is much much smaller.

Comment: So the 14S8P array is 14 in series per channel and 8 channels. But to calculate current it's 20mA per channel so 160mA. Then the output voltage is ~3.2V forward voltage * 14 = 44.8V.

Comment: Please leave a link to the LED array.

Comment: It is a discrete array of blue leds with a forward voltage of 3.2V and forward current of 20mA. The arrangement is following the application guidelines in the data sheet.